# Conditional onclick based on checkbox, dropdown, and quantity fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an onclick attribute of an insert button (or a product id pasted into the addtocart() function referenced by the onclick attribute of the insert button) dependent on conditions. I got 2 checkboxes, one drop-down with 4 products, and a quantity field (limited to numbers: 0,3,5,8).

As an example:

Scenario 1: [checkbox 1:checked;checkbox 2:unchecked; product 4:selected;quantity:5;] = Internal_product_id: 987987

Result:

```js
function addToCart(){
  CartJS.addItem(987987);
}
```

Scenario 2: [checkbox 1:checked;checkbox 2:unchecked;product 4:selected;quantity:3;] =  Internal_product_id: 123123

Result:

```js
function addToCart(){
  CartJS.addItem(123123);
}
```

All 64 scenarios are relevant and would need to be taken into account.

So far, I got the following code:

```html
-<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en' class=''>
<head>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<style>

   
.bg {
 width: 100%;
}


.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

  
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    
}



.count-input {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #000
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.count-input .incr-btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.count-input .incr-btn:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}

.count-input .incr-btn_2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.count-input .incr-btn_2:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}


.count-input .incr-btn_3 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.count-input .incr-btn_3:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}

.count-input.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}
.count-input.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}
.count-input.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.count-input.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: none;
    padding: 10.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}


.sum_output {
    background: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.accordion_img {
  width:200%;
}

.checkbox_align_0 {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.checkbox_align_1 {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.checkbox_align_2 {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 29px;
}

.checkbox_align_3 {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="name"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="password"], select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul class="flex-container">

  <li class="flex-item">
     <section class="grid__spans-25">
  <select id="list1">
   <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Product 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-imagesrc="http://placehold.it/64x64">Product 4</option>
</select>
  
</section>
  </li>
  
</ul>


<input class="checkbox_align_1" style="width:20px;height:20px;" type="checkbox" id="include" name='include' data-target="drop_1" />


<input class="checkbox_align_1" style="width:20px;height:20px;" type="checkbox" id="include_4" name='include_4' data-target="drop_1" />

<div id="drop_1" class="sum_output">= $ 0.00</div>

<div class="count-input space-bottom">
  <a class="incr-btn" data-action="decrease" data-target="drop_1" href="#">–</a>
  <input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1" type="text" name="quantity" value="0"/>
  <a class="incr-btn" data-action="increase" data-target="drop_1" href="#">+</a>
</div>      
       
<input type="button" class="button_mobile" value="Add" onclick="addToCart()">
<script>                  

var _EXTRAVAL = 1;

var _EXTRAVAL_4 = 1;



$(".incr-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set variable for the method
    var button = $(this);
    var labelNb = button.parent().find('.quantity');
    var labelPrice = $("#" + button.attr('data-target'));
    var currentNb = button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
    var newNb = 0;

    // Remove 'inactive' class
    $('.incr-btn[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');

    // Increase or decrease
    if (button.attr('data-action') == "increase") {
   if ((currentNb) >= 8 ){
   // nichts machen
   }else{
    if ((currentNb == 0)||(currentNb == 5)){
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) + 3;
    }else if((currentNb == 3)){
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) + 2;
    }
  
   }
        
    }
    
    if (button.attr('data-action') == "decrease") {
   if ((currentNb) <= 0 ){
   // nichts machen
   }else{
    if ((currentNb == 8)||(currentNb == 3)) {
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) - 3;
    }else if((currentNb == 5)){
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) - 2;
    }
  
   }
        
    } 


    var isExtra = $("#include").prop('checked') ? _EXTRAVAL : 0;
    var isExtra_4 = $("#include_4").prop('checked') ? _EXTRAVAL_4 : 0;
    $(labelNb).val(newNb);
    $(labelPrice).css('display', 'block').html("=  $" + String((((newNb) * 55) + (isExtra) + (isExtra_4)).toFixed(2)));
    
});

$("#include").on('click', function(){
    // Set variable for method
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var labelPrice = $("#" + $(".incr-btn").attr('data-target'));
    var labelPriceFloat = parseFloat(labelPrice.html().substring(4));
    
    // If checkbox is check, increse price
    if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
        labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat + _EXTRAVAL).toFixed(2)));
    } else {
        labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat - _EXTRAVAL).toFixed(2)));
    }
});


$("#include_4").on('click', function(){
    // Set variable for method
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var labelPrice = $("#" + $(".incr-btn").attr('data-target'));
    var labelPriceFloat = parseFloat(labelPrice.html().substring(4));
    
    // If checkbox is check, increse price
    if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
        labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat + _EXTRAVAL_4).toFixed(2)));
    } else {
        labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat - _EXTRAVAL_4).toFixed(2)));
    }
});

    
</script>   

<script>

function addToCart(){
  CartJS.addItem(Internal_product_id);
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

> > Solution with fixed external IDs

Since I had to use external ID to reference products the missing element for me was this code for each product:

```html
  if ((document.getElementById("include").checked == true) && (document.getElementById("include_4").checked == true) && (document.getElementById("list1").value == 1))
              {var ShowButton_value_1 = document.getElementById('ShowButton_value_1').value
              var id14 = "11192355913771"
              CartJS.addItem(id14,ShowButton_value_1);}
```

I added the quantity variable ShowButton_value_1 to the CartJS function directly.

Please see J.M. Echevarría's solution for a solution that generates unique id's within the code itself.

Comment: just to c if I got it right, a state is the combination of the 2 checkboxes, the selected option (out of 4) and the selected quantity (also out of 4) and you need to map that state to a product id, that can't be right, right? cause it would mean you got max 64 product ids? tell me what I am missing please

Comment: That's correct actually

Comment: Edit: I need to consider all 64 scenarios. Any thoughts?

Comment: actually, now that I think about it, in your examples you left out the second checkbox, does it mean that this is not a possible scenario `[checkbox1:checked;checkbox2:checked;product 4:selected;quantity:5;] = id` but these are `[checkbox1:checked;product4:selected;quantity:5;] = id` and `[checkbox2:checked;product4:selected;quantity:5;] = id`. what I'm trying to ask is: do you take BOTH checkboxes into consideration to generate an id, or just one OR the other every time?

Comment: Yes, I take both into consideration, all 4 scenarios. I will update the question accordingly to reflect this better.

Comment: lastly, how do you know, given a combination, the id for that combination. Example: if you are given this state: [ch1:true, ch2:false, select:4, qntty: 5], how do you know that corresponds to id 987987, why is it not, for instance, id 542145 the correct one. I know you just wrote it as an example but, is there a criteria you follow to come up with the right id or do you have every combination already related to its id somewhere? or maybe the whole question is about you not having a way of generating a unique id for each combination yet?

Comment: I have id numbers for all combinations already in a different system. As an example, the number 41325234 represents 5 times product No 1 with both add-ons selected.

Comment: Clarification: That being said, I don't know how to write a code smart enough to associate this number with a certain state and paste it into the cartjs function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need then is to grab the values from the four elements and, using some criteria **you have to have** (this is the important detail, no one can help you with that), come up with the ID. For example, if I were to do it generating my own ids, which would always be unique since every combination of the elements is unique, it'd be like:

```
function addToCart(){
    var id = ($("#include").prop('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '' + 
        ($("#include_4").prop('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '' + 
        $("select#list1").val() + '' + 
        $('#ShowButton_value_1').val();

    CartJS.addItem(parseInt(id));
}
```

The single quotes are just a hack to force them to add like strings.

`parseInt` is just in case you need the argument as an integer.

Hope this sheds some light down your path. LMK

Comment: I didn't even think of such an approach and feel I should have mentioned that the ids are generated (I am not able to change the ids in the other system in order to come up with my own logic).

Comment: Is there possibly a way to structure an if else statement like (i am just using two arguments and two possible outcomes for simplicity):

Comment: function addToCart(){ if (($("#include").prop('checked') == 1) && ($("#include_4").prop('checked') == 0) {CartJS.addItem(9999999); } else {CartJS.addItem(1111111); }; } –

Comment: I think I figured it out and will post the answer in a few